# render full form

Tags: 7, forms

I need to render a full form, including the `<form>....</form>` tags. Any ideas how can I do that?

I tried `drupal_render()` and `render()`. The form elements are rendered but there is no `<form>` tag in the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a properly formatted form array to render, which you get by calling [`drupal_get_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7). After that you just run it through `render()` as you're currently doing:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('form_id');
print render($form);
```

Comment: apparently the tag was there but the chrome inspector did not see it. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as I expected.

Comment: @MariusIlie It would be improbable a Drupal form is rendered without `<form>` tags.

Answer (score -1):

You need `theme_form()` in your form theme: `drupal_render()` your #children, then `theme_form()`.
And you can put HTML around the elements.

```
$buildform = '<div>'. drupal_render($form['element1']) .'</div>';
$buildform .= drupal_render($form['element2']);
$buildform .= drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
$buildform .= drupal_render($form['form_id']);
$buildform .= drupal_render($form['form_token']);
$form['element']['#children'] = $buildform;
$output = theme_form($form);
```